# How might I avoid a global mutable variable in this code?

Tags: web-scraping, rust, global-variables, unsafe

The following code is meant to print `There is page two.` if it finds a certain `div` on [this website](https://www.pasion.com):

```
use reqwest;
use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::Name;
use std::io;

static mut DECIDE: bool = false;

fn page_two_filter(x: &str, url: &str) {
    if x == "pSiguiente('?pagina=2')" {
        unsafe {
            DECIDE = true;
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Give me the URL with the search results?");
    let mut url = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut url)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let url = url.trim();
    let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;

    Document::from(html.as_str())
        .find(Name("div"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("onclick"))
        .for_each(|x| page_two_filter(x, url));
    unsafe {
        if DECIDE == true {
            println!("There is page two.")
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Dependencies from Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.15"
reqwest = "0.11.9"
scraper = "0.12.0"
select = "0.5.0"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

Is there a safer way, i.e. without the `unsafe` blocks of code, of doing what that code does?
Wanting to avoid global mutable variables, I've tried with redefining `page_two_filter` and an if statement with the result of the call to `page_two_filter`, like so:

```
fn page_two_filter(x: &str, url: &str) -> bool {
    if x == "pSiguiente('?pagina=2')" {
        return true;
    }
    false
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Give me the URL with the search results?");
    let mut url = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut url)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let url = url.trim();
    let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;
    if Document::from(html.as_str())
        .find(Name("div"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("onclick"))
        .for_each(|x| page_two_filter(x, url))
    {
        println!("There is page two.")
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

but compiler does not allow me doing this saying:

```
mismatched types expected `()`, found `bool`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for_each()`, I guess you need [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find).

This returns `Some( found_element )` if found or `None` if not found.

You can then use the `Option` returned by `find()` with `if let`, `match`, `is_some()`...

```rust
    if let Some(_) = Document::from(html.as_str())
        .find(Name("div"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("onclick"))
        .find(|x| page_two_filter(x, url))
    {
        println!("There is page two.")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the

> mismatched types expected `()`, found `bool`

error is because there is no semicolon after the println statement in the for_each closure.

Secondly, the filter is actually a one-liner, which could be integrated in that very closure

```rust
fn page_two_filter(x: &str, url: &str) -> bool {
  x == "pSiguiente('?pagina=2')"
}
```

Lastly, you already use various iterator methods, so why not continue?

```rust
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
 println!("Give me the URL with the search results?");  
 let mut url = String::new();
 io::stdin().read_line(&mut url).expect("Failed to read line");
 
 let url = url.trim();
 let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;
 if let Some(_) = Document::from(html.as_str())
    .find(Name("div"))
    .filter_map(|n| n.attr("onclick"))
    .find_map(|attr| if attr == "pSiguiente('?pagina=2')" {
        Some(true)
    } else {
        None
    }) {
    
        println!("There is page two.");
    }

    Ok(())

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) which returns **true** on first find of condition, **false** otherwise:

```rust
fn page_two_filter(x: &str, url: &str) -> bool {
    x == "pSiguiente('?pagina=2')"
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Give me the URL with the search results?");
    let mut url = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut url)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let url = url.trim();
    let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;

    let found = Document::from(html.as_str())
        .find(Name("div"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("onclick"))
        .any(|x| page_two_filter(x, url));

    if found {
        println!("There is page two.");
    }
}
```